# jQuery to find the first following element with a given class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following element saved to a jQuery object:

```
<tr class="delivery-method">...</tr>
```

I want to find the first element with class `delivery-price` that is not earlier in the DOM.

There are other elements with the same class `delivery-method`. I need to find the first element with class `delivery-price` that is after this particular element that has been saved to the jQuery object.

Some limitations that might be helpful:

- An element with class `delivery-price` will never be inside the element saved to the jQuery object.
- The sought after element with class `delivery-price` is always a direct sibling to the element saved to the jQuery object.

Comment: jquery has a method just for that, .first() https://api.jquery.com/first/ you can also use a first child selector https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

Comment: Are all such elements siblings, or could they be e.g. cousins?

Comment: Gah - the OP edited the question while I wasn't looking.  Go ahead and close!

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to make any assumptions about the relative position of the elements, the most generic way is to first find *all* such elements:

```
var $all = $('.delivery-method');
```

and then look for the position of the one you have:

```
var index = $all.index(myElement)
```

at which point the next one is:

```
var $next = $all.eq(index + 1);
```

although of course this will fail if you're already on the last element.